# When I have two instances open it didn't ask to choose any one in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

When I open more than one instance of any app. like files or vscode (Visual Studio Code). Then I open another app. When I want to go back on vscode, It opens my last opened app's instance. I think it should ask me to choose which instance I want to open. I have checked settings also, but I didn't get any option to fix this issue.

Can anyone help me to fixed this issue ?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu flavor?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 18.04.2

Comment: I'm a little uncertain as to what you mean by "go back on..." are you `alt+tabbing`? If so I think this is expected behaviour as it doesn't see them as "two separate instances" but more "two separate programs" and just as when you `alt+tab` regularly it doesn't ask "which program do you want to go to?" It just goes to the most recently used one. In any event you may file a feature request, or better patch this yourself.

Comment: @j-money I have tried this feature in multiple system and it always ask to open which instance/program I want to open but this is only not open in my pc only.

Comment: I ask again, are you `alt+tabbing`?

Comment: When I just go with mouse it didn't ask for that. So for choose I have use this key for select my instance.

Comment: As it stands, your question is almost completely devoid of information, and it is unclear by what you mean by choosing whether you are selecting a window with your mouse click, alt tabbing, or something else. I'd suggest editing your question adding pictures of what you mean if need be, but more importantly clarifying **exactly** what you are doing to reproduce your outcome

Comment: ok @j-money. I'll add video link soon.

Comment: Hey @j-money This is video URL. I hope you will get idea of my issue. https://we.tl/t-Aik97q3FcO

Comment: I'm not going to download your video, either host it on youtube or some other video playing site

Comment: @SachinShah You just need to right-click on the icon -> pick your window.

Comment: @JacobVlijm But why should I need to go with right click. And as I show in my video in other ubuntu it's not required.

Comment: I'm afraid I've lost you.What other Ubuntus?

Comment: I mean in other ubuntu 18.04 os. As I have used two os in video.

Comment: @j-money I have upload video in my driver and hear it's link. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Oe16XlC8SI9EgPD53XA1Tn0ie9gd5lg2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I'm able to fixed my issue using this small command.

```
dconf reset -f /
```

This command used to reset all the settings from custom settings to default.

Answer (score 4):

Without getting into the lengthy discussion of what exactly went wrong, but I have feeling that is related with the GNOME Shell, which is the default Ubuntu desktop. I don't use Ubuntu Official just because of that. My suggestion is you do the same. As alternative,

Use [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/), for all sorts of reasons, unless you are religiously attached to Ubuntu Official/GNOME Shell.

Not the answer you were looking for, but you *will* love [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/).

---

You can install MATE DE along with current installed DE with

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

and compare your experience in it with any previous.

Comment: +1; There are other community flavours too (which are officially supported, but developed and maintained by volunteers), Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu Studio, Xubuntu. Try them live (booted from a USB pedrive or DVD disk) and select the version that you like best.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes there are also good os are available. For this small issue, do you really think that I should go with another os ? Actually I have many software's installed in my ubuntu 18.04.02. Can you please help me to fixed my issue ?

Comment: As per you if it's GNOME Shell issue then can you please help to fixed that GNOME issue ?

Comment: No I can't, as I don't use it. Sorry it is not the answer you were looking for.